# PyAutoGUI fails at recognizing single color images

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, pyautogui

When using the function pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image,confidence=0.9) on a single color .png file the python code returns a Box(left=0, top=0, width=x, height=y)
where x and y are the dimensions of the image provided. It does not work with the .png file open.

I have tried other images like a specific windows desktop icon which works with a confidence interval of 0.9.

Example:

[steam .png image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsJRN.png)

Terminal: Box(left=973, top=893, width=90, height=92)

however when I try using a solid color png image: the code returns the top left of the screen

[pink .png image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nENw4.png)

Terminal: Box(left=0, top=0, width=247, height=175)

Code:

```py
import pyautogui
image=dir+"steam.png"
loc=pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image, confidence=0.9)
print(loc)
```

Edit: If I add region=(x,y,width,height) the function returns None

Comment: Did you try different solid colours? Did you try reducing the confidence till it works?

Comment: Yes I have tried plenty of different colors, they all give the false positive result of 0,0. I have tried confidence 0.5-1 all result in the false positive of 0,0